# Tornado file uploads - high memory usage

Tags: python, memory-leaks, tornado

We have a tornado application running behind nginx, supporting user file uploads (I just use `self.request.files` to access the uploaded files). The maximum file size is 10MB and this is set in the nginx config, so the python process should never see files larger than that.

I've noticed that every time a user uploads a file, the memory goes up by a little. But I can't figure out a pattern there. I've tried to figure out if there are any memory leaks (using `pympler` and `objgraph`) but couldn't find anything particularly suspicious. They only show me that the top memory consuming objects are strings and dicts, with combined object sizes not more than 7-8MB. If the uploaded file itself would still have a reference after the request completed, then I would also expect the `bytes` type to be reported by `pympler` and/or `objgraph`, which I don't.

I wonder how to best deal with this situation. Is this another case of the "[high water](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python.html)" behavior? Would switching to `stream_request_body` yield better results? Or is it easier to simply restart the process once it hits a certain threshold?